# Single button used for enable/disable user how to identify button status using Selenium Webdriver

Tags: java, selenium, button, using

Here single button is used for enable/disable user, when you click on the button  and if the button is in disabled mode then it becomes enable (user becomes active) or if the button is in enabled mode then it becomes disable (user becomes inactive)
Here my concern is how can i get the status of the button is in what status so i can perform operation based upon the status of button.

Here  is code snippet for the same..

When button is in enabled mode.

```
<a id="13" class="btn btn-xs btn-success inactive" title="Click to Inactivate" href="javascript:void(0);" data-active-inactive="inactive">
<span class="ion-checkmark"></span>
</a>
```

When button is in Disabled mode.

```
<a id="13" class="btn btn-xs btn-danger active" title="Click to Active" href="javascript:void(0);" data-active-inactive="active">
<span class="ion-android-close"></span>
</a>
```

Here is Image of the front-end.
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you get the attributes of the element then check it like:

Python:

```
elm = driver.find_element_by_id("13")
class = elm.get_attribute("class")
if "inactive" in class:
    print "button is disabled"
else:
    print "button is enabled"
```

Java:

```
Webelement elm = driver.findElement(By.id("13"));
String c_elm = elm.getAttribute("class")
if c_elm.contains("inactive"){
    System.out.println("button is disabled")
}
else{
    System.out.println("button is enabled")
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, My code is in Java  it would be more helpful if your solution is in Java.

Answer (score 0):

The class and title attributes are different for button disable and enable states.
You can use any of these.

For Button Enabled mode:
driver.findElement(By.xpath(@class="btn btn-xs btn-success inactive"))
or
driver.findElement(By.xpath(@title="Click to Inactivate"))

For button disable state:
driver.findElement(By.xpath(@class="btn btn-xs btn-danger active"))
or
driver.findElement(By.xpath(@title="Click to Active"))

Answer (score 0):

Here is code that was written and worked for me.

```
enableDisableVendor = driver.findElement(By.id(enableDisableVendorBtnId));
        enableDisableBtnStatus = enableDisableVendor.getAttribute("class");

        System.out.println("Button Status :" +enableDisableBtnStatus);

        if (enableDisableBtnStatus.equals("btn btn-xs btn-success inactive"))
        {
            System.out.println("Vendor is Enabled");


        }

        else if(enableDisableBtnStatus.equals("btn btn-xs btn-danger active"))
        {
            System.out.println("Vendor is Disabled");
        }

        else
        {
            System.out.println("Something went wrong");
        }
```